# Seasonality and work days in time series

Tags: r, time-series, seasonality

I have a time series which is daily data for workdays only. There is an almost obvious seasonality comparing the plot of the raw data that appears at the end of each month. However, there are not the same number of workdays for every month. Some times a month has 20 or 21 workdays. Do you have any idea how to treat the data? Do you suggest to manipulate the data in order to create a series with a constant frequency? The problem is that in R I have to set the frequency before running the ARIMA.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Forecast? Study the seasonal pattern? Look at what exogenous variable affect the series?

Comment: Thank you Rob for your reply

Yes I am trying to make a forecast with R. Maybe one case would be to group the data in weekly averages and set frequency =4, so the seasonal pattern would be exactly at the 4th week of each month. But I would like to make daily forecasts.
Thanos